# Importing Excel with Coldfusion - Receiving strange date format mm\/dd\/yyyy

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using ColdFusion 9 to import data from an Excel (2007, xls) spreadsheet. One of the columns being imported is a date field.  In most cases, the date comes across fine, however in some instances it appears that something strange is happening with the date format.  It comes across as `mm\/dd\/yyyy`.  I don't know what is adding those additional `\`'s.  The specific error is obvious:

```
"11\/15\/2012 is an invalid date or time string."
```

Looking directly at the spreadsheet, and within the cells themselves, the date appears formatted correctly as `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

**Follow-Up**

Thanks for the helpful answers.  In the end, the best solution was from CoderSeven.  I used `Replace(dateString, '\', '', 'all')` to remove the offending slash and process the data through.  This proved to be the best solution because I am processing spreadsheets from potentially tens of thousands of individuals, and while I control the format of the spreadsheet they use, I cannot control whether they type or cut-and-paste the data into the fields.  Ultimately I would love to know where that extra slash came from, but this solution worked well.

Comment: Are you sure coldfusion does not treat it as DD/MM/yyyy by default?

Comment: `Replace(yourdate, '\', '')` I tend to take the stance of - If a MS product does something weird, the best solution is to just make sure you can handle that weirdness instead of trying to figure out where that weirdness is coming from - Saves alot of time an effort.

Comment: Do you mean Excel shows the type of the cell as being date, as well as the cells just being formatted correctly? POI (which ColdFusion uses for Excel integration) will know the cell type and CF may well use that to interpret the cell content

Comment: It may be a bad cell format. Do you have a sample file (and code) that produces these results?

Comment: @CoderSeven - Since that seemed to do the trick, you should post it an answer. So it is easier for others to find. dkighton- If you are still curious - and have a *sanitized* sample file - post it and we could help you figure out the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer as to why this is happening, but it is a work-around.

Just use `Replace(yourdate, '\', '')`.

Personally, I tend to take the stance of:

If a MS product does something weird, the best solution is to just make sure you can handle that weirdness instead of trying to figure out where that weirdness is coming from.

Not that MS products are bad, it just usually saves you alot of time an effort.

Answer (score 0):

"11\/15\/2012 is an invalid date or time string." One problem might be that the dates on your spreadsheet are not strings they are excel time values - which are basically integers. Perhaps converting these cells to a text format using:
    =TEXT(C7,"mm/dd/yyyy")

might solve the problem. Just to be safe I would change to format to text as well. Good Luck.

Comment: IMO converting dates/numbers to "text" usually exacerbates any problems :/ `text()` also converts empty values to `01/00/190x`, which means another exception to handle.

Comment: @Leigh I'm not sure how many programs use the same date system that excel uses - so I think it must be a common task to do conversions from it to other systems. Plus in the error message it seems to be expecting a string. You could easily solve that with an isblank() check. As in =if(ISBLANK(C7),"",TEXT(C7,"mm/dd/yyyy"))

Comment: (Edit)Given that this sounds like a programatic import, there is not much benefit of trying to fix the server file. Ultimately you still need to validate the values before importing. Because there is no guarantee all cells in a particular column will contain a valid "date" - no matter what format is used. IMO it makes more sense to just read in the file "as is". Automatically handle simple issues you can anticipate, and reject the rest.

Comment: @Leigh I think the data that is actually in the files is important, so I'm just trying to point him in the direction of a possible cause of his problem, which might help him to fix the problem on the Coldfusion end. Obviously, you have alot more experience with coldfusion so maybe you can help him with that.

Comment: @Stpan101 - Well the OP suggests a file upload and import process of abitrary user files. If that is correct, there is only so much you can do server side. Since Excel files are not rigidly structured like a db table, this issue is only one - of any number of issues - that can occur with the import. Personally I would not go crazy over it, since you still need to validate everything pre-import anyway.